# Error: Propiedad no existe al intentar cargarlo en la vista

Tags: laravel

El problema que tengo es que, al momento de querer pasarle datos a mi vista por medio de la ruta, no me carga ni la imagen y me pierde el css de mi menú. No entiendo por qué y solo es al momento de colocarle los datos, y al momento de leerlos en mi vista me tira error de que la propiedad no existe.

Este es mi datatables donde capturo los valores para enviarlos:

```
   <div class="box" align="center">

     <div class="box-body">
         <div class="content">
              <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
                  <thead>
                     <tr>
                        <th>PROVEEDOR</th>
                        <th>DESC_ENLACE</th>
                        <th>NO_FACTURA</th>
                        <th>ID_ENLACE</th>
                        <th>VALOR_PAGO</th>
                        <th>PERIODO</th>
                        <th>FECHA_FACTURA</th>
                        <th>OPCIONES</th>
                                <th>OPCIONES</th>
{{--                                <th>OPCIONES</th>--}}
                            </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                   @foreach($datos as $datos)
                      <tr>
                         <td>{{$datos->proveedor}}</td>
                         <td>{{$datos->desc_enlace}}</td>
                         <td>{{$datos->no_factura}}</td>
                         <td>{{$datos->id_enlace}}</td>
                         <td>{{$datos->valor_pago}}</td>
                         <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($datos->periodo)->format('d-m-Y')}}</td>
                         <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($datos->fecha_factura)->format('d-m-Y')}}</td>

                         <td>
                           <a  href="{{url('editar_datos/'.$datos->id_enlace.'/'.$datos->periodo)}}" class="btn btn-primary active" >Editar</a>
                         </td>
                          <td>
                           <a  href="{{url('eliminar/'.$datos->id_enlace.'/'.$datos->periodo)}}"  class="btn btn-danger active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Eliminar</a>
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                       @endforeach
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Esta es mi ruta la cual recibe las variables, el problema es que al momento de colocarles las variables, me pierde la imagen que tengo de fondo y mi menu, no sé por qué.

```
  Route::GET('editar_datos/{id_enlace}/{periodo}',[
        'as'=>'editar_datos',
        'uses'=>'editar_datos@editar_datos'
    ]);
```

Este es mi controlador:

```
    class editar_datos extends Controller
{

    public function editar_datos($id_enlace, $periodo)
    {

        $info = DB::table('fcm_enl_ter_fact')->where('ID_ENLACE', $id_enlace)->where('PERIODO', $periodo)->get();

        return view('editar')->compact('info');
    }
}
```

Esta es mi vista en la cual quiero mostrar mis datos para editarlos, pero no me está mostrando los datos: me dice que la propiedad no existe y los datos sí me los carga en mi controlador pero no sé por qué no me los quiere mostrar en mi vista.

```
<body background="img/tigo4.jpg">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TIGO</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
            aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="{{url('/') }}">INICIO</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

        <!-- Default box -->
            <div class="box" align="center">

                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="content">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="inputEmail4">Proveedor</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{$info->proveedor}}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="inputPassword4">Desc_enlace</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputAddress">Id_enlace</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" >
                            </div>


                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.box -->
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema puede ocurrir por que en esta parte`return \View::make('editar')->with(['info' => $info,]);` 
estas devolviendo el array traído de la base de datos dentro de el indice info,tomando en cuenta que solo devuelves un array a la vista te recomiendo que devuelvas los valores a la vista de esta forma: `return view('editar')->compact('info');`

Comment: lo hice ahora como puedo mostrar cada dato de estos en mis input

Comment: en la propiedad `value` puedes pasar el nombre de la variable ejemplo: `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="documento" name="documento" value='{{ $info->documento}}'>
`